# Scaling image and recalculate(x,y)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, transform, scale

I have an image of size 11900x3200 and a point marked on it at (2745,2730). This size is too big for displaying on iPhone screen. I want to scale down an image to 3200x2000. How do I calculate my new (x,y) position on the new scaled down image.

Comment: This seems more of a math question but shouldn't 11900/3200 = A, 2745/A = x1, 3200/2000 = B, 2730/B = y1 work? Your image is going to looked squished though with how much you're scaling horizontal vs how much you're scaling vertical.

Comment: Hi,i tried this however the new x1,y1 are being marked at a different point.I lose my original marked location and its  marked at a different location

Comment: shouldn't it be at x = 2745 * 3200 / 11900; y = 2730 * 2000 / 3200; But did you noticed that you are changing the proportions?

Comment: hi,that didnt work.I checked manually using photoshop.The desired coordinates come around(584,830) approx.Not sure how to get to that.Also the proportions are changing.How to i calculate the ideal size to fit in iphone 5 screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ratio Based Image Scaling To Achieve this.

This Method you can get Proper image without pixalate.

```
 float ori_height=image.size.height;
 float ori_width=image.size.width;



    NSString *orientation=@"";

    if (ori_height>ori_width)
    {
        orientation=@"PORTRAIT";
    }

    if (ori_width>ori_height)
    {
        orientation=@"LANDSCAPE";
    }


    if ([orientation isEqualToString:@"LANDSCAPE"])
    {





        if (ori_height<300)
        {

             int height_ratio=ori_height/4;
            int width_ratio=ori_width/4;

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width_ratio,height_ratio));




           UIImage *currentImage = [self imageWithImageSimple:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(width_ratio, height_ratio)];


        }
        else
        {
            int height_ratio=ori_height/6;
            int width_ratio=ori_width/6;



            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width_ratio,height_ratio));


             UIImage *currentImage = [self imageWithImageSimple:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(width_ratio, height_ratio)];

        }

    }
    else if ([orientation isEqualToString:@"PORTRAIT"])
    {
        //NSLog(@"portrait");
        if (ori_height<300)
        {
           ...
        }
        else
        {
            int height_ratio=ori_height/6;
            int width_ratio=ori_width/6;



            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width_ratio,height_ratio));


         UIImage  *currentImage = [self imageWithImageSimple:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(width_ratio, height_ratio)];

            //[currentImage drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, width_ratio, height_ratio)];

        }
    }



    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then Another Method

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithImageSimple:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize); 

[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];  

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();   

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();   

return newImage;
}
```

Comment: hi,how do i recalculate my (x,y) position on the image after it has scaled down